# In RFC 2409 does SIG_I and HASH_I refers to the same?

Tags: hash, cryptography, digital-signature, vpn, rfc

In RFC 2409, IKE authentication by digital signature we see the following:

```
`Initiator              Responder
-----------                 -----------
HDR, SA             -->
                <--  HDR, SA
HDR, KE, Ni         -->
                <--     HDR, KE, Nr
HDR*, IDii, [ CERT, ] SIG_I     -->
                <--     HDR*, IDir, [ CERT, ] SIG_R
`
```

also, we see it's mentioned:

-In both modes, the signed data, `SIG_I` or `SIG_R`, is the result of the
negotiated digital signature algorithm applied to `HASH_I` or `HASH_R`
respectively.

-In general the signature will be over `HASH_I` and `HASH_R` as above
using the negotiated prf, or the HMAC version of the negotiated hash
function (if no prf is negotiated).

what does the above means? , how `SIG_I` and `SIG_R` are get calculated and verified?

I understand that the HASH_I and HASH_R are calculated like the following:

`HASH_I = prf(SKEYID, g^xi | g^xr | CKY-I | CKY-R | SAi_b | IDii_b ) HASH_R = prf(SKEYID, g^xr | g^xi | CKY-R | CKY-I | SAi_b | IDir_b )`

and the `SKEYID` is different depends on the authentication method in use, and for digital signatures it's like the following:

For signatures: `SKEYID = prf(Ni_b | Nr_b, g^xy)`

now, I would like to understand what does it mean by "`SIG_I` or `SIG_R`, is the result of the
negotiated digital signature algorithm applied to `HASH_I` or `HASH_R`
respectively." ? does this mean `SIG_I =  prf (HASH_I)`?

Comment: This is not a programming question and thus is off-topic here on Stack Overflow. I think it might be on-topic on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/), but check their help pages for guidance first. Also, if your question is more about the basics of asymmetric cryptography and digital signatures, look elsewhere on the web for tutorials/primers. Even wikipedia should provide a decent start.